# didreceivememorywarnings message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning

In my app if I have a view that has been deallocated (via modal dismiss or navigation stack pop) and I get a memory warning after that, my app crashes.

I've tested by putting a modal create/dismiss very early on in my app that looks like this:

```
WWebViewController *webViewController = [[WWebViewController alloc] initWithPath:@"http://www.google.com"];
        [webViewController setIsModal:YES];
        WMainNavController *navController = [[WMainNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The web view is pretty simple:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNavigationDefaultsWithTitle:@"Loading..." withBackButton:YES withSearchButton:YES deepLinked:false];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView scalesPageToFit];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.path]]];
    [self showNoConnectionImageIfNecessary:NO];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

...

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
    [webView stopLoading];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [webView setDelegate:nil];
    webView = nil;
}
```

However, simply presenting and then dismissing this view followed by simulating a memory warning gives this:

```
*** -[WMainNavController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xba953c0
```

I've tried this by calling WWebViewController directly without WMainNavController, tried by using a regular navigation controller, tried simply pushing something to a nav stack. It always crashes if I have popped or dismissed a view anywhere in the app.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? If I progress through the app without dismissing/popping it handles memory warnings fine, and there is only one screen before this which presents this screen as a modal and is the root view of the program.

I'll provide any extra information needed, has anybody seen something like this?

Edit -- This is an ARC implementation.

Edit -- Here is a screenshot of my instruments with zombies on:

[image]

It looks to me as everything is normal. It deallocates properly on dismissal, but for some reason the memory warning call is trying to access that view controller. I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Sorry, yes this is ARC. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Do you see this issue if you take out all your extra `webView` calls in `dealloc`? Typically you shouldn't start new asynchronous loads (as `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` does) in the middle of deallocating.

Comment: Most of what's in the dealloc method is stuff I was working with to deal with memory issues when deallocating the webView. Stupid things always try to hang on to memory. However, this crash happens no matter what view I dismiss/pop, it doesn't have to be  this particular web view (or a web view all at, could be any view controller). To directly answer your question, yes, it still happens if I remove all of that stuff in my dealloc method.

Comment: Usually in a low memory situation the app will "Release" any views "not" being used like for instance if it's the current view. So trying to access anything in one of those views without explicitly instantiating it again will result in a crash. You might try unloading the cache(s) in the viewWillUnload: But that's probably not why its crashing.  The debugger says it all...Your trying to access something in WMainNavController or WMainNavController itself after it's gone. Is 0xba953c0 WMainNavController? try po 0xba953c0 and see what it says.

Comment: @HubertKunnemeyer Apps tended to do that pre-iOS6, but not since. I should have stated that my app is targeting iOS6 and up only, in which viewDidUnload has been deprecated. It seems like somewhere in my app something is keeping a snapshot of everything that's ever been allocated or something and didReceiveMemoryWarning is noticing that, but instruments shows WWebViewController and WMainNavController both get completely deallocated prior to this happening.

Comment: If I po that address, I get this: *** -[WContainerViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xad45750 or similar depending on which view was most recently hit via didReceiveMemoryWarning. Thanks for the tip, that makes me feel like I'm making some sort of progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across a similar issue, I can't really explain how to fix it, but I can tell you what I did to make my issue magically disappear.

I essentially began removing any categories/controllers/whatever that affect many or all other major components of my app from compile sources in the build phases of my target. I then commented out code accordingly so my app would build to where I needed it to go to test. Eventually I isolated a UIViewController category that was 'causing the issue' and removed all of the methods from it as well as an NSString extern variable.

This fixed the problem, but when I was trying to figure out what method was causing it...turns out none of them were. When I uncommented everything and was back to where I started with the category it continued to work, no more crashes.

I'm happy it works now, but damned mystified that I'll never really know why it broke in the first place.